# I want to adjust multiple displacements maps

Tags: three.js

I want to add several displacement maps to my mesh. 
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx65c.png)

But I don't know how to do this.

I tried this.

```
var image = textureLoader.load('images/nail.jpg');
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color:0xffffff,
        displacementMap: image,
        displacementScale : 10,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
material.needsUpdate = true;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30,30,30);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);
```

add image button source

```
$('#submit').click(function (){
    var path = document.getElementById('file').value;
    path = path.split('\\');
    path = path[2];
    console.log(path);
    material.displacementMap = textureLoader.load('images/'+path);
});
```

[Here's the reference site.](https://seller.troupejewelry.com/customproduct) You can see it by adding an image.

Comment: Can you please try it according to the official displacement map example? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap . BTW: You can only apply a single displacement map per material. The title of your question sounds like you want to apply multiple displacement maps at once (which is not possible).

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to use custom shader materials.

Comment: @Mugen87 Already tried this. The image in the text is one with two images of two.

Comment: @prisoner849 I'm a novice at threejs, so I don't know how to use shaders.